# How to give groovy closure parameter a type

Tags: java, groovy, functional-programming

I know closures have implicit type 'it' such that we can define a function

```
def int foo(int num, Closure closure){
  def sum = num
   sum+=closure.call(1)
}
```

then i call this function like

```
def total = foo(1,{it+1})
print total
//prints 2
```

My question  is how do i force the closure to take an explicit parameter of type int. Like how we can define lambda functions in java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`@ClosureParam`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/stc/ClosureParams.html) to annotate your `Closure` argument declaration with its parameters specifications. In your particular case:

```
import groovy.transform.stc.ClosureParams
import groovy.transform.stc.FirstParam

int foo(int num, @ClosureParams(FirstParam) Closure closure) {
    def sum = num
    sum += closure.call(5)
}
```

where `FirstParam` is a *hint* that says that the argument of `closure` is of type equals as the *first parameter* of this method.

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/groovy/so/a56212874)